# On clicking empty space in my constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button in a constrained layout.  when I press the button I open a recycler view.
How can I detect a press in the empty area of the layout and then close down or make vanish the recycler view.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

In view you use getHitRect to get area of view. You can use code like:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        btnAction.getHitRect(rect);
        if (rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
            //open recycler view
        } else {
            //Do something
        }

        return false;
    }else {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```